# How can I add windows shared printer to Network service user?

Tags: windows, networking, printer

I have a web application in a tomcat container running as windows service, I need to print a network printer (\OTHERPC\Printer) but I cannot find it. I found the the service account cannot see shared printers and only running Tomcat as a standard user it can see the shared printers. I also try to switch user the service to "network service" without success.

How can I add shared printer to Network service user?

I tried to run psexec and many other tools to get a cmd of Network Service but I could not get access and moreover, I don't know if it is possibile and how add a shared printer via cmd.

Comment: Are the computers where the container and shared printer exist both in a domain?

Comment: No, they are in Workgroup (no domain) .